# Что значит домен по отношению к ООП?

Tags: ооп, домен

Готовлюсь к экзамену и там вопрос: "Объекты, классы, домены и отношения между ними". Все логично, но что здесь значит "домен"? Пространство имен, обособленную часть предметной области, множество значений типа или что-то еще?
Просто в книге по ООП тоже встречал этот термин и не очень понятно, что конкретно под ним автор подразумевает...
Может кто-нибудь знает, объясните, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Домен это и есть предметная область.

В дополнение к этому можно сразу определить понятие **доменный объект** — это объекты в программах, описывающие **объекты предметной области**.

Удачи вам на экзамене :)

*Сам сдавал ГОСы пару дней назад*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, если бы ГОСы :) А откуда информация? Можете дать ссылку почитать подробнее?

Comment: Ну тут неплохие лекции http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2190/237/lecture/6134?page=1

Comment: спасибо большое!